# Korean Characters Showing as non-utf8 In the Rest API, but Showing Correctly in Wordpress DB

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, elementor

I have a Wordpress site in English, with a few characters in Korean.  I'm using Elementor Pro for this site.  My character set is set to utf8 in my wp-config file and my database uses utf8mb4.

In the wordpress editor, the korean characters show properly, in the database the characters are also stored correctly (showing properly when viewed through PhpMyAdmin), and in the Elementor editor the characters also show correctly.

However, when viewing the rest api endpoint for my site through a browser, the characters show up as `\uc6e8\uc774\ube0c\ud22c\uc5b4\uc2a4`.

When googling these codes I get a "This is not a valid unicode character". [Here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c6e8/index.htm)

Why are the characters showing up correctly in the database, the Wordpress editor, and the Elementor editor, but I'm being shown non utf8 character codes in the rest api?

Comment: https://symbl.cc/en/C6E8/ as well as https://old.unicode-table.com/en/C6E8/  say *Hangul Syllable We 웨*…

Comment: @JosefZ can you expand?  I see the links you included but they show \C6E8 (css) or U+C6E8 (html) or U+C6E8 (unicode).  The codes I'm getting directly from the rest api are different.  Wondering why?

Comment: `\uc6e8\uc774\ube0c\ud22c\uc5b4\uc2a4` notation are [Unicode escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences).

Comment: I see so this is standard behavior when viewing content in the browser from a rest api that contains foreign characters?